# join two class list to another list

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda

I have 2 objects : ParentOne and ParentTwo :

```
class B
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string AtterC { get; set; }
        public string AtterE { get; set; }
        public int AtterG { get; set; }
    }

    class ParentOne
    {
        public string AttA { get; set; }
        public List<B> AttrBList { get; set; }
    }

    //-----------
    class ParentTwo 
    {
        public List<C> AttrCList { get; set; }
    }
    class C
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int AtterF { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to join two list class with id

```cs
ParentOne parent1 = get(..)
ParentTwo parent2 = get(..)

     var query = parent1.AttrCList.Join(
            parent2.AttrBList,
            l1 => new { l1.id },
            l2 => new { l2.id },
            (item1, item2) => new
            {
                id= item1.id,
                name = item2.name,
                AtterC = item1.AtterC,
                AtterE  = item1.AtterE,
                AtterG  = item1.AtterG  
            });
```

but, I get an error about join.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Try following :            ParentOne one = new ParentOne();
            ParentTwo two = new ParentTwo();

            var results = (from o in one.AttrBList
                          join t in two.AttrBList on o.id equals t.id
                          select new { one = o, two = t})
                          .ToList();

Comment: I get an error over  parent1.AttrCList.Join  with this message "The type arguments for method 'EnumerableJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(1Enumerable<TOuter>, lEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, TKey>, Func<Tlnner, TKey>, Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>)' cannot be Project.test01 inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Answer (score 0):

yes, i solve this problem with

```
 var res = from item1 in parent1.AttrCList
                  join item2 in AttrCList
                      on item1.id equals item2.id
                  select new
                  {
                         id= item1.id,
                         name = item2.name,
                         AtterC = item1.AtterC,
                         AtterE  = item1.AtterE,
                         AtterG  = item1.AtterG  
                  };
```

anyone, do you know, faster solution ?